# How to estimate the error in Leave One Out Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Is there a proper way to perform LOOCV and estimate the error as the mean of all the train data.
I already perform a K-FOLD CROSS-VALIDATION as gives:

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv = 10, scoring = "accuracy")
print('mean score and the 95% confidence interval of the score estimate')
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

I was wondering how would be the proper way for LOOC since this one suppose a cv=N(number of instances). I was reading about it in the documentation but what I am looking for is the estimated error for LOOCV.
What I came across with was this code but it doesn't seem to generate an accuracy or an error for each validation:

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
 loo = LeaveOneOut()
 for train, test in loo.split(X):
     print("%s %s" % (train, test))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use your LOO with the `cross_val_score()`

Comment: You mean by using for instance, cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=150, n_jobs=-1) where 150 is the number of instances. But by doing this I get an error which says: ValueError: All the n_labels for individual classes are less than 150 folds.

Comment: No i mean by using `cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=loo, n_jobs=-1)`